Filing an extension with IRS without an ITIN
I need to file a USA tax return as a non-resident alien. I have never filed a USA tax return before and don't have an ITIN. I need to apply for an extension beyond June 17 as I am awaiting a document my tax preparer needs in order to file my return. They have prepared a form W-7 to file with my return once it is ready.
My tax preparers are saying that I can't file for an extension without an ITIN, but the guidance on the IRS website suggests filing form 4868 and stating 'ITIN to be requested'.
Is it possible to apply for an extension without an ITIN and having never previously filed a return? If yes, should I file it myself without going through my tax preparer?

From the instructions for the form 4868, Part I line 2:

If you’re a nonresident or resident alien and you don’t have and
aren’t eligible to get an SSN, you must apply for an ITIN. Although
an ITIN isn’t required to file Form 4868, you’ll need one to file your
income tax return. For details on how to apply for an ITIN, see Form
W-7 and its instructions. If you already have an ITIN, enter it
wherever an SSN is requested. If you don’t have an ITIN, enter “ITIN
TO BE REQUESTED” wherever an SSN is requested

Confirm with your tax preparer how to proceed.

To be clear, this is on the paper form. I don't know but it may be that this option isn't available on efiled 4868 -- and paid preparers are generally required to efile.

@dave_thompson_085 I don't think you can efile with W7

You can't efile a return that needs to attach W7, but 4868 isn't a return and you don't attach W7 to it, so that's irrelevant for this Q
